# Bootstrap 3 Grid how to make nested columns all the same height as the largest

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, grid

I am trying to get bootstrap 3 to ensure all the columns are the same height across the page.

I can get this to work when I have 3 columns much like the example here:
[How can I make Bootstrap columns all the same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height)

The issue I am having is that I want to have nested columns and these nested columns will need to be x% each equalling up to 100% of the height of the largest parent column. I can't seem to find a solution to nested columns.

So I need the nested columns to fill their parent column depending on the height percent provided to the nested columns css.

The css height percentage will be provided via jquery .css()

```
.row {
    display: table;
}

.row [class*="col-"] {
    float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: top;
}

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-3 ">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450">
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 " style="background-color: grey">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 " style="background-color: green">30%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 " style="background-color: blue">20%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-12 " style="background-color: red">50%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 " style="background-color: grey">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 " style="background-color: green">25%</div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12 " style="background-color: orange">75%</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-3 " style="background-color: blue">
    100%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try "`display: flex;`" property to the parent.

Comment: Display flex helps with the width, but not with the height.

Comment: Here is the simple demo for the "Flex" property in codepen. https://codepen.io/satheesh_design/pen/qPbdKV

Comment: Thanks for the example, but the problem I am trying to solve is when a column has a nested column.

Comment: I have updated my codepen link with one layer of the nested column. Please have a look on it.

Answer (score 0):

@Satheesh Kumar thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Flex was definitely what I wanted. Here is a link to what I was trying to achieve.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/XeXXpQ

```
<div class="equal-height-container">
    <div class="first">
      <img src="http://placehold.it/250x450">
    </div>

    <div class="second">
      <div class="second-a">A</div>
      <div class="second-b">B</div>
      <div class="second-c">C</div>
    </div>
    <div class="third">

    </div>
  </div>



    .equal-height-container {
          max-width: 900px;
          margin: 0 auto;
          display: flex;
        }
    .first {
      background-color: #FFF;
      padding: 20px;
      flex: 1;
    }

    .second {
      background-color: yellow;
      flex: 2;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }

    .third {
      background-color: yellow;
      padding: 20px;
      flex: 2;
    }
    .second-a {
      background-color: #c0dbe2;
      flex: 2.5;
    }

    .second-b {
      background-color: #cdf1c3;
      flex: 1;
    }

    .second-c {
      background-color: red;
      flex: 1;
    }
```